# Test failing with 403 FORBIDDEN response after upgrading to springboot 3.1.x

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

**SpringBoot** Version : 3.1.8
**Code**:

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
package com.example.TestRestAPI.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration("SecurityConfiguration")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable() // Disabling CSRF protection
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasRole("USER")
                        .anyRequest().denyAll() // Denying all other requests
                )
                .httpBasic(); // Using HTTP Basic authentication
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("password").roles("USER").build());
        return manager;
    }
}
```

RESTApiController.java

```
package com.example.TestRestAPI.controller;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/sayHello")
public class RESTApiController {
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_ZIP = "application/zip";
    @GetMapping(produces = { MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_ZIP })
    public String sayHello1(@RequestHeader("Accept") List<String> acceptHeader) throws MyException {
        List<String> acceptTypes = new ArrayList<>(acceptHeader);
        // remove all acceptable types from the list
        acceptTypes.remove(CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_ZIP);
        acceptTypes.remove(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);
        acceptTypes.remove(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        // anything left is unacceptable
        if (!acceptTypes.isEmpty()) {
            throw new MyException("Error in content-type");
        }
        return "{'greeting':'Hello!'}";
    }
}
```

RestControllerAdvice

```
package com.example.TestRestAPI.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;


@RestControllerAdvice("com.example.TestRestAPI.controller")
public class RESTApiAdviser {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorInfo handleMyException(MyException ex){
          return new ErrorInfo (HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE.value(), "Error in content-type");
    }
}
```

Custom exception

```
package com.example.TestRestAPI.controller;

public class MyException extends Exception {

    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
    public MyException (String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

ErrorInfo

```
package com.example.TestRestAPI.controller;

import lombok.Data;

/**
 * Common representation of an error
 */
@Data
public class ErrorInfo {
      private final Integer status;
      private final String detail;
      private String type;
      private String title;
      private String instance;
}
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  mvc:
    problemdetails:
      enabled: true
```

The below testcase(`testInvalidAcceptHeadersWithoutJsonType`) for my controller was working fine with springboot 2,

```
package com.example.TestRestAPI.controller;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RESTApiControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;


    @Test
    public void testInvalidAcceptHeadersWithoutJsonType(){
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip"), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = testRestTemplate.withBasicAuth("user","password")
                .exchange("/api/v1/sayHello", HttpMethod.GET,  httpEntity, Resource.class);
        assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
}
```

but after upgrade to springboot 3 it failing as instead of 406 getting 403, gives below error

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: No acceptable representation at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:256) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:194) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
```

When I update my testcase as below, its working fine

```
 @Test
    public void testInvalidAcceptHeadersWithJsonType(){
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip"), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = testRestTemplate.withBasicAuth("user","password")
                .exchange("/api/v1/sayHello", HttpMethod.GET,  httpEntity, Resource.class);
        assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
```

Am I missing any changes needed for springboot3.